# Difference between GAS, GWT, and Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-apps-script

I am new to app script so I found the documentation a bit confusing. I see there is a way to develop google apps in eclipse using a GWT plugin. But when I dig deeper I find out this method needs me to know well Java, which I dont. I know well javascript and I thought the plugin could let me write appscript.gs files on eclipse but I dont know how. How do i distinguish GAS, GWT and app engine (layman please) and is there a way to write GAS offline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if these information will help but here...

The differences between GAS, GWT, and GAE (Google App Engine) are the following:

- GAS is a JavaScript cloud scripting language that provides easy ways to automate tasks across Google products and third party services. So, actually you cannot write GAS offline, and you have to go online (http://script.google.com).
- GWT is a development toolkit for building and optimizing complex browser-based applications. So, it helps you developping your product more easily.
- GAE is a platform as a service (PaaS) cloud computing platform for developing and hosting web applications in Google-managed data centers.

Even if you're not comfortable with Java, you can still developp a Google app very easily.

I would suggest you to use the Google App Engine for Python. Everything is explained here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview

You can developp your app offline with eclipse and then publish it on Google's servers.

Even if you do not know Python, the tutorial explains everything quite clearly (and Python it is a very friendly and funny programming language ;) )

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I build my web app entirely on GAS and host it on my own domain? 2. Does a GAS app run on app GAE by default?

Comment: GAS apps are meant to be published to the Chrome Web Store (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_chrome_web_store) or to the Gallery (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_gallery), so I don't think you can host GAS on your own domain.

Comment: Concerning GAE, you don't need GAS to developp Google Apps and you could just use javascript, HTML, CSS, but you will have to write some code (just a little bit don't worry ;) ) in other language like Python or Java (as I said Python is the best choice for you I think). With GAE, you can define custom domains https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: thank you @Littm. I am now getting a better understanding so can I write a GAS standalone app that displays a google map that users can pin details and fellow users see the details and send emails?

Comment: @TechyTimo: I guess you can. Here are some useful links for the Map service: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_maps , and the Email functionnality: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_mail . Hope these will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Google App Script enables you to write a web application (in Javascript) that runs on Google's servers, but it isn't related to Google App Engine.  For example, I wrote a GAS web app to allow teachers at my son's school to reset the passwords of a student's Google Apps for Education accounts (a frequent IT problem that teachers have to deal with is is forgotten passwords).

Google App Script is more general than just web apps; you can use it to manipulate Google spreadsheets, docs, and sites too.  For example, we used a Google Form to collect data from parents into a spreadsheet, and I then used GAS to normalize and reformat that data into another sheet.

Comment: Thank you so much, so can I embed a map on a GAS app that will be public to visitors and they can pin data on it?

Comment: Do you mean Google Maps, or just an image?  Can you tell us more about the context in which your app will run?  Are you trying to create a "gadget" that can be embedded in Google Sites, or a web page that will be accessed directly by users?  I think it will be easier to answer with more info.

Comment: oh, i meant an interactive map, to be used for pinning posts so that others can see and comment. I thought getting it on a standalone app for a moment before i asses the reception then later host it on my domain. what do you think is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

GAS applications can also run on Google Sites. So you can write your script, publish it, and then run it from a Apps Script box on a Google sites page. (You have to change 'scripts' to 'sites' in the url).